# Is there a stat block available for Fraz-Urb'luu?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, npc

I have been experimenting with my own campaign which has ended up including Fraz-Urb'luu as a central antagonist. My intention is that the group does not have to fight/kill him, however in order to be prepared I have looked around for a stat block for him just in case. Unfortunately I have been unable to find any indication of any supplements or rulebooks with a 5th edition compatible stat block for him.

Presumably, if such a stat block exists, it would be an infringement to post it here, but if I know what I need to buy I am happy to make the purchase. Do any of the Rage of Demons/Out of the Abyss supplements include a stat block for him?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, a statblock for Fraz-Urb'luu is included in Appendix D of the *Out of the Abyss* campaign book. Minor spoiler for that campaign:

> It's actually kind of weird, because that campaign is set up so that it's impossible to fight him at any point. But I guess it's nice of them to include a statblock anyway.

Comment: It might be worth noting that Fraz-Urb'luu's statblock (along with those of a few other demon lords) was reprinted in *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*, with a slight adjustment to HP: "350 (28d10 + 196)" in OOTA, "337 (27d10 + 189)" in MTOF. (The Con saving throw modifier was also adjusted from +15 to +14, presumably to bring it in line with the apparent proficiency bonus of +7 indicated by the other stats added to the +7 Con mod.)